# How do I parse with both Day of Week and Month in date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a string `Mon Mar 28 00:00:00 EDT 2022` which I want to parse but it's not working

```
dateFns.parse(theDate, "eee MMM d HH:mm:ss X yyyy", null)
```

Getting

> RangeError: The format string mustn't contain `eee` and `MMM` at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try this:

```
dateFns.parse(theDate, "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss X yyyy", new Date())
```

but this still wrong, the "EDT" string cause error, I've tried with "-04" instead, it works. So maybe you should try some way convert the "EDT, UTC,.." string to timezone format "-04" "+07"